# Orderedlist number position

Tags: html

I want to achieve this:

```
1.Rod    The lazy dog.
2.Jane   The lazy cat.
3.Freddy The active goldfish.
```

However, I get this:

```
Rod      1. The lazy dog.
Jane     2. The lazy cat.
Freddy   3. The active goldfish.
```

This is my html:

```
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    span
    {
        width: 60px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        clear: left;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <ol>
        <li><span>Rod</span> The lazy dog.</li>
        <li><span>Jane</span> The lazy cat.</li>
        <li><span>Freddy</span> The active goldfish.</li>
    </ol>
</body>
</html>
```

What can I do to position the list numbering at the beginning?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need anything but the width and the display, actually:

```
span 
{ 
    width: 60px; 
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

[Tested](http://jsfiddle.net/cdeszaq/PJhdq/), this works for me in IE9, Chrome, and Firefox.